# LINQ to SQL doing a Union and Left Outer Join

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, union, left-join

I have 3 tables. 2 contain lists of files that I need to do a UNION on to get all the unique files, then I want to do a left outer join against the 3rd table to find all the files that are in the 3rd table only and not in the other 2.

To do the UNION I have the following:

```
var imageUnion = (from img in dc.ImageT1
                  select img.filename).Union(
                  from img in dc.ImageT2
                  select img.filename);
```

Now, to get the files only in the 3rd table I would do a left outer join as such:

```
var query = from image in dc.ImageT1
            join active in dc.ActiveImages on image.filename equals 
            active.filename into gj
            from subimage in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where subimage.filename == null
            select new { image.filename, image.size };
```

I understand how to do the left outer join simply against ONE table, but how do I get the result set of my first query into the left outer join? Basically, instead of doing the left outer join against ImagesT1 I want to do it against the imageUnion result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select more than one property in your Union; The current result is IEnumerable<string> (assuming your filename is a string).

```
var imageUnion = (from img in dc.ImageT1
                  select new { Filename = img.filename, Size = img.size }).Union(
                  from img in dc.ImageT2
                  select new { Filename = img.filename, Size = img.size });
```

Then you should be able to use it in the second query to replace dc.ImageT1.

Though thinking more on it, the Union may not work with 2 anonymous types; To support that, maybe it'd be worth defining a class that has only a Filename and Size?

```
public class TempImage
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

var imageUnion = (from img in dc.ImageT1
                  select new TempImage() { Filename = img.filename, Size = img.size }).Union(
                  from img in dc.ImageT2
                  select new TempImage() { Filename = img.filename, Size = img.size });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select from your first query instead of the image table again.  Something like:

```
var query = from image in imageUnion
            join active in dc.ActiveImages on image.filename equals 
            active.filename into gj
            from subimage in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where subimage.filename == null
            select new { image.filename, image.size };
```

edit: You will also to have to edit your imageUnion query to select size as well as filename (and any other columns you need in your final query).

Comment: That was what I originally tried, but I think because imageUnion result set is an anonymous type it doesn't work. What I mean is when you try to do image.filename in this example, it doesn't have the filename property.

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't want to select the entire img in the first query because the result set would be too large (as in the image is in a blob or something to that effect)?

Comment: As Chris points out, if you don't want to use your Image class, you could create a scaled down class with just Filename and Size and everything should work as you want it to.